# Enabling bluetooth disconnects wireless

Tags: 12.04, wireless, bluetooth, vaio, disconnect

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a SONY VAIO VPCSB1Z9E. Wireless and bluetooth are working fine seperately but they won't work at the same time.

For example: Wireless is connected and working fine when bluetooth is disabled but when I enable bluetooth, in 10 seconds, wireless disconnects from access point and asks for WPA password.

How can I get bluetooth work without interfering wireless connection?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug where the two peripherals are sharing the same
bus and when one turns on, it crowds out the other. You would be better
served by filing a launchpad bug and uploading full apport diagnostics
so we can better observe what's going on. Please update this post
with the bug #. Thanks.